# Winforms-Reactiveui 6.5 Binding to ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, listbox, reactiveui

I am developing a small app to test MVVM pattern with WinForms, using ReactiveUI (6.5, latest version so far). I made some progress with commands (ReactiveCommand) and some Bindings between properties and TextBoxes.
I am stuck now trying to bind a ReactiveList of items to a listbox (my intention is to automatically update the listbox, once an element is added to the list, and see the new element inside the listbox).

Here the code:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class PersonViewModel : ReactiveUI.ReactiveObject
{ 
(...) 
public ReactiveList<int> Ids { get; private set; }

    public PersonViewModel ()
        {
            Ids = new ReactiveList<int>();
            (...) 
        }

//The command that adds a new item inside the list
private void AddPerson(int id)
        {
            Ids.Add(id);
        }
}
```

**MainForm**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IViewFor<PersonViewModel>
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
            //PersonsListBox.DataSource = ViewModel.Ids; -> this was an idea, it doesn't work either
            this.WhenActivated(d =>
                {
                    d(this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.Ids, x => x.PersonsListBox.DataSource)); // Binding attempt, doesn't seem to be working         
                    d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.AddPersonCommand, x => x.AddPersonButton)); // Command, it works
                });            
        }

        public PersonViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get { return ViewModel; }
            set { ViewModel = (PersonViewModel)value; }
        }
}
```

Any ideas on that? My intention is to use it in different controls that make sense to be used with lists (dataGrids, listViews, listBoxes etc.), and hopefully there is a method to do it, in the same way it is done with textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ReactiveBindingList` instead `ReactiveList`.